# ForEach loop overwriting output in Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm working on a PowerShell script to loop through an array of API queries for each day of the week.

I've come across an issue... when I loop through the script the output for each day is overwritten which results in the value for every day being the same.

Where am I going wrong?

```
DATE        PAGE    RANGE   VALUE
18/05/2020, PAGE 1, 0_2000, 12345
18/05/2020, PAGE 1, 2001_4000, 23456
18/05/2020, PAGE 1, 8001_40000, 45678
19/05/2020, PAGE 1, 0_2000, 12345
19/05/2020, PAGE 1, 2001_4000, 23456
19/05/2020, PAGE 1, 8001_40000, 45678
20/05/2020, PAGE 1, 0_2000, 12345
20/05/2020, PAGE 1, 2001_4000, 23456
20/05/2020, PAGE 1, 8001_40000, 45678
…
```

```
#Date
$GetDate = [datetime](Get-Date).AddDays((-1 * (Get-Date).DayOfWeek.Value__) - 6).Date
$week = @(0..5)
$WeeklyOutput = @()

#API Query
$REQUESTS = @(
    ("PAGE1","0_2000","QUERY_1",""),
    ("PAGE1","2001_4000","QUERY_2",""),
    ("PAGE1","8001_40000","QUERY_3","")  
)

#Structures the 'OutputClass'
class OutputClass {
    [string]$DATE
    [string]$PAGE
    [string]$RANGE
    [string]$VALUE;
}

#Iterates through the script for the days specified
$week = @(0..6)
Foreach ($dayofweek in $week) {
    $DailyOutput = @()
    $StartDate = $GetDate.AddDays($dayofweek)
    $start = ([int]::Parse((Get-Date $StartDate -UFormat %s)))*1000
    $EndDate = $StartDate.AddDays(1)
    $end = ([int]::Parse((Get-Date $EndDate -UFormat %s)))*1000
    $PrintDate = $StartDate.toString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    #Iterates through all the Requests     
    Foreach ($REQUEST in $REQUESTS) {

        $REQUEST[3] = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $REQUEST[2] | Select -expand results

        #Appends each requests to the Daily Output
        $DailyOutput += [OutputClass]@{DATE=$printdate;PAGE=$REQUEST[0];RANGE=$REQUEST[1];VALUE=$REQUEST[3]}                
    }

    #Appends each Daily Output to the Weekly Output                                
    $WeeklyOutput += $DailyOutput 
}

$WeeklyOutput
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try defining `$WeeklyOutput` and `$DailyOutput` before the `foreach` loop with `$WeeklyOutput = @()` and the same with `$DailyOutput` and see if it changes anything

Comment: `$WeeklyOutput` was already defined before the `foreach`. I've tried it with `$DailyOutput` aswell but I am still seeing the same output.

Comment: `$StartDate` is based on some undefined variable `$GetDate`. Where does `$GetDate` get its value? Shouldn't that be `$StartDate = (Ge-tDate).AddDays($dayofweek)` ?

Comment: I've added the `$GetDate` section that I use. It retrieves the start of the week and cycles through 7 days. I've used it for other scripts and it works successfully, however when I try to use it with `ForEach` it overwrites the `VALUE` everyday, as illustrated in the example.